# 400 Bad Request (MVC+Spring+DB) method add mappend in POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, bad-request

I'm doing and application for a job training. And I can't find the error in my app.
I create a simple view using FreeMarker, and when I write into the form the informations and send them, I've got an Bed Request in the method add mapped like a @PostMapping("/add"). For this reason the information that I'm sending into the DB does't write. I configured correctly the bean into class AppConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="Biblioteca.Controller")
@PropertySource("classpath:Biblioteca.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment env;
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver configResoler() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver= new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
   // resolver.setCache(true);
    return resolver;
}
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer configurerFM() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer config= new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/view/");//dico dove si trovano i file

    return config;
}
@Bean
//ricordarsi di mettere dentro file di proprerty
public DataSource getDataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource db= new DriverManagerDataSource();
    db.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("Biblioteca.db.driver"));
    db.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("Biblioteca.db.url"));
    db.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("Biblioteca.db.username"));
    db.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("Biblioteca.db.password"));
    return db;
}
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter=new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    //serve per creare un entity manager di jpa
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory= new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());//classi che utilizzano entity manager
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(){
   // JpaTransactionManager jtm= new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManager().getObject());
    return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactory().getObject());

}

@Bean
public LibriService getLibriService(){
    return new LibriImpl();
}
```

}

This is Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LibriController {
@Autowired
private LibriService libri;


@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String idProdotto, ModelMap mm){
    if(idProdotto!=null){
    // Libri p=  libri.getById(Integer.parseInt(idProdotto));
     mm.addAttribute("libroDaModificare", libri.getById(Integer.parseInt(idProdotto)));
    }

    return new ModelAndView("index", "listaL", libri.getAll());
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public String add(@ModelAttribute("datiLibri") Libri libr){
    libri.add(libr);
    return "redirect:/";
}


@PostMapping("/update")
public String update(@ModelAttribute("datiLibri") Libri libr){
    libri.update(libr);
    return "redirect:/";
}


@GetMapping("/delete")
public String delete(@RequestParam("id") String idProdotto){
    if(idProdotto!=null)
    libri.delete(Integer.parseInt(idProdotto));
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

This is my Service interface

```
public interface LibriService {
public void add(Libri libri);
public void update(Libri libri);
public void delete(int id);
public Libri getById(int id);
public List<Libri> getAll();
}
```

This is a service class

```
enter code herepublic class LibriImpl implements LibriService {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional
public void add(Libri libri) {
em.persist(libri);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void update(Libri libri) {
    em.merge(libri);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(int id) {
em.remove(getById(id));
}

@Override
//@Transactional
public Libri getById(int id) {
    return em.find(Libri.class, id);
}

@Override
//@Transactional
public List<Libri> getAll() {
Query q= em.createQuery("SELECT libri FROM Libri libri");
return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

In console trace I've got no errors-
In browser I'v got just this message:
Type Status Report

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

What's wrong here?

Comment: I found the problem. I have't converted java.util.Date to sql.Date

Comment: Add this as an answer and then accept it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: @JoãoDias Done. But for a moment I can't accept my answer by my myself: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Ah yes, I always forget about the waiting period. Then do it in 2 days, so that the question is closed as answered ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I have not converted java.util.Date to sql.Date.
For this reson I've got "400 Bad Request".